# How to use nth-type on post blogspot

Tags: blogger, blogger-themes

I want to add different colors to one post title that I just published on blogspot / Blogger, I have tried using nth-type etc., but it doesn't work properly. Please help me on this.

I have made a picture, more or less like this:

[image: how to make this]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use pseudo class `:first-child` to select first post title as the following

```
.post:first-child .post-title a { color: red }
```

Update:

If elements are not in the same container you can use javaScript selector

Add this before `</body>` tag to select the first `.post-title`

```
<script>
   document.querySelector('.post-title a').style.color = 'red';
</script>
```

Comment: I tried it on my blog ( https://cobadownload1.blogspot.com/ ), and all the title colors turned red

Comment: Ok, because your post divs are not in the same container. see update

Comment: thank you, it works.
one more thing I want to ask,
how to add the word "update" at the beginning of the title, but for one recent post. like using :: before

Comment: Ok, in this case you need to add more than one property to the first title and this is not a good thing using JS, My advice is to add class name `first-post` by JS then use CSS to add more properties. `document.querySelector('.post-title a').classList.add('first-title');`

Comment: And after that you can use CSS like this `.first-title:before { content: "Update" }` also `.first-title { color: red }`